# AWK Lookup between columns in the same file(similar to vlookup)

Tags: awk, lookup

I have a single input file.
I need to scan values/numbers of column 1 and 2  in column  3 and if matches print $1 and $2 with the corresponding $4, like output as below.
Any help appreciated.

To match for the first column in $3,tried this code but it didn't work.
the logic was to put $3 in an array and scan $1 in it.

```
awk -F ',' '{a[$3] } { if ($1 in a) {print $1":" $4 } else {print $1, "NA"}  }' 1.csv
```

Input

```
 345,1314,567,index-1
 344,1315,566,index-2
 343,1316,565,index-3
 342,1317,1316,index-4
 241,1318,563,index-5
 340,1319,562,index-6
 439,1320,561,index-7
 318,1333,337,index-8
 337,1335,559,index-9
 236,1336,558,index-10
 ,,311,index-11
 ,,1314,index-12
 ,,1333,index-13
 ,,3444,index-14
 ,,344,index-15
 ,,2008,index-16
 ,,342,index-17
 ,,1320,index-18
 ,,543,index-19
 ,,340,index-20
 ,,12233,index-21
```

output

```
 345:#N/A
 344:index-15
 343:#N/A
 342:index-17
 241:#N/A
 340:index-20
 439:#N/A
 318:#N/A
 337:index-8
 236:#N/A
 1314:index-12
 1315:#N/A
 1316:index-4
 1317:#N/A
 1318:#N/A
 1319:#N/A
 1320:index-18
 1333:index-13
 1335:#N/A
 1336:#N/A
```

Comment: Your text and your example do not agree.  Please clarify what you want and show what you have tried so far.

Comment: sorry for the confusing explanation,example input and output is valid.I have tried to match first column in the begining but still need a big help.awk -F ',' '{a[$3] } { if ($1 in a) {print $1 $4 ":"} else {print $1, "NA"}  }' 1.csv

Comment: What have you tried?  Very difficult to help you with your code when you don't include the code.  [Put it in your question](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/28387099/edit), not just a comment.

Answer (score 0):

```
$ cat nash.awk
NR == FNR { a[$3] = $4; next }    
($1 in a) { print $1 ":" a[$1] }  
($2 in a) { print $2 ":" a[$2] }
$1 && !($1 in a) { print $1 ": #N/A"}    
$2 && !($2 in a) { print $2 ": #N/A"}
```

Note that we provide the text file twice as the awk script makes two passes (see more explanation below):

```
$ awk -F, -f nash.awk nash.txt nash.txt

1314:index-12
345: #N/A
344:index-15
1315: #N/A
1316:index-4
343: #N/A
342:index-17
1317: #N/A
241: #N/A
1318: #N/A
340:index-20
1319: #N/A
1320:index-18
439: #N/A
1333:index-13
318: #N/A
337:index-8
1335: #N/A
236: #N/A
1336: #N/A
```

Explanations:

```
NR == FNR { a[$3] = $4; next }
```

When NR == FNR we know we are reading the file for the first time. Here we save all the `$4` values corresponding to `$3`. The `next` means we skip all the further commands.

```
($1 in a) { print $1 ":" a[$1] }
```

If we're here we know we are reading the file for the second time. Check if field 1 matches any field 3's and if so, print it along with the field 4 saved in the step above.

```
($2 in a) { print $2 ":" a[$2] }
```

Same as above, but for the second field.

```
$1 && !($1 in a) { print $1 ": #N/A"}
```

Similarly, if the first field is *not* found, print the N/A message.

```
$2 && !($2 in a) { print $2 ": #N/A"}
```

Sames as above for second field.