# Filter out rows from column A based on values in column B

Tags: awk

I have a CSV file that contains two columns. First column is a list of all subscribers and second column is a list of subscribers who need to be excluded from a mailing:

```
all,exclusions
alice@example.com,charles@example.com
bill@example.com,alice@example.com
charles@example.com
daisy@example.com
esther@example.com
```

I need to end up with an output of all subscribers from first column who are not listed in the second column. The desired output is something like this:

```
bill@example.com
daisy@example.com
esther@example.com
```

So far all I have is this:

`awk -F, '(NR>1) {if($1!=$2) {print}}' subs.csv`

This of course will only filter out the rows when there are matching values in both columns on the same row.
Thanks for any help.

Comment: [This thread](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28387099/3832970) might help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With an array. I assume that there are no duplicates in the first column.

```
awk -F ',' 'NR>1{
              array[$1]++; array[$2]--
            }
            END{
              for(i in array){ if(array[i]==1){ print i } }
            }' file
```

As one line:

```
awk -F ',' 'NR>1{ array[$1]++; array[$2]-- } END{for(i in array){ if(array[i]==1){ print i } } }' file
```

Output:

```
esther@example.com
daisy@example.com
bill@example.com
```

Answer (score 2):

For completeness, remove excluded entries, including repeated values.

**Data**

```
$ cat file
all,exclusions
alice@example.com,charles@example.com
bill@example.com,alice@example.com
charles@example.com
daisy@example.com
daisy@example.com,alice@example.com
daisy@example.com,charles@example.com
daisy@example.com
esther@example.com
esther@example.com
alice@example.com
```

```
$ awk -F ',' 'NR>1 && NF==1{ all[$1]++ }
  NR>1 && NF==2{ all[$1]++; excl[$2]++ }
  END{ for(i in excl){ all[i]=0 };
    for(i in all){ if(all[i]>=1){ print i } } }' file

esther@example.com
daisy@example.com
bill@example.com
```

Answer (score 1):

With two arrays. First field `$1` is the `list of all subscribers` and this is used as an index of an array called `a`. Second field `$2` is the `list of subscribers who need to be excluded` and it is used as index of array `b`. We get `subscribers from first column who are not listed in the second column` this way in the `END` part: `for (i in a) if (!(i in b)) print i` using the two arrays:

```
awk -v FS=',' '
        NR > 1 {a[$1];b[$2]}
        END{for (i in a) if (!(i in b)) print i}
' file
esther@example.com
daisy@example.com
bill@example.com
```

Or using the `continue` statement which causes the next iteration  to begin.

```
awk -v FS=',' '
        NR > 1 {a[$1];b[$2]}
        END{for (i in a) if (i in b) continue;else print i}
' file
esther@example.com
daisy@example.com
bill@example.com
```